BRST charge action on fields

How can we prove that the BRST charge $Q$ acts on bosonic fields as $$\delta A(x) = \epsilon[Q,A(x)]\tag{1}$$ and on fermionic fields as $$\delta\psi(x) = \epsilon\{Q, \psi(x)\}\tag{2}.$$

And how should we consider the BRST charge? Is it a generator or a conserved charge?




Eqs. (1) & (2) are the standard way a Noether charge $Q$ generates a symmetry transformation, cf. e.g. this & this related Phys.SE posts.
More generally, an operator $\hat{F}$ is transformed as
$$\begin{align}\hat{F}~\longrightarrow~e^{\epsilon\hat{Q}}\hat{F}e^{-\epsilon\hat{Q}}~=~&e^{[\epsilon\hat{Q},~\cdot~]_{C}}\hat{F}\cr
~=~&e^{\epsilon[\hat{Q},~\cdot~]_{SC}}\hat{F}\cr
~=~&\hat{F}+\epsilon[\hat{Q},\hat{F}]_{SC}+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2),\end{align}\tag{A}$$
where $[\cdot,\cdot]_{C}$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]_{SC}$ are the commutator and supercommutator, respectively. In eq. (A) we have assumed that $\hat{Q}$ and $\epsilon$ carry the same Grassmann parity.
See also e.g. this related Phys.SE post.

In case of the BRST symmetry, the charge $Q$ is Grassmann-odd.
In terms of value, a Grassmann-odd charge $Q$ is soul-valued, i.e. a definite non-zero value does not make sense, cf. e.g. this related Phys.SE post.



I understand how to show that $\delta A(x) = \epsilon [Q,A(x)]$ but not how to get that $\delta \psi(x) = \epsilon{Q,\psi(x)}$. Indeed if I write $\psi(x) \rightarrow U^{\dagger}\psi(x)U$ I get the commutator not the anticommutator.

I updated the answer.
